# $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin{1\over n}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that: $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin{1\over n}=0$,  $\forall n \in \mathbb N$. Please, I really need some help.

Comment: How do you define $\sin$?

Comment: Please, sir, can I have some … more?

Answer (score 4):

$|\sin x|\le |x|$, so $$-x\le \sin x\le x$$
$$-\frac{1}{n}\le\sin\frac{1}{n}\le\frac{1}{n}$$.

Using Squeeze Theorem, we will get $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\frac{1}{n}=0$

Comment: and if I use the epsilon definition I just need to put $e \gt{1\over n}$ ?

Comment: Hmm, yes! But it's easier using known inequalities @DavidHernandez

Answer (score 1):

You know that $\sin 0 = 0$ and $\sin' = \cos$, so $|\sin'(x)| \le 1$ for all $x$. The mean value theorem gives $|\sin x - \sin 0 | \le 1 \cdot |x-0| = |x|$. Hence $|\sin x| \le |x|$, and hence $|\sin \frac{1}{n} | \le \frac{1}{n}$.

It follows that $\sin \frac{1}{n} \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

By the continuity of $\sin$, $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin\left(\frac 1 n\right)=\sin \left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)=\sin0=0.$$